# How do you color a specific part of an image in JavaFX?

Tags: java, image, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I did some research on how to color specific parts of an image using JavaFX, but I can't seem to find any information about this. I want to be able to color the different sections (each with a different color) of the following image in JavaFX:

[image: image with different sections]

Can it be done easily?

**EDIT:**
This picture is much clearer in showing what I'm trying to do:

[image: image with different sections]

Comment: Short answer: yes it can be done easily. There are several ways to do this. Which is appropriate depends a lot on why you need this.

Comment: Well, I have an image that has a round object, and I want to be able to color this image between the line boundaries with something like `image.setFill(Color.RED, region3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Group and Rectangles with different colors and positions for this.

Here is example:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(400,100);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(400,125);
        Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(400,175);
        Rectangle rect4 = new Rectangle(200,250);

        rect1.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        rect2.setFill(Color.RED);
        rect3.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        rect4.setFill(Color.GREEN);

        rect2.setLayoutY(100);
        rect3.setLayoutY(225);
        rect4.setLayoutX(200);
        rect4.setLayoutY(150);

        root.getChildren().addAll(rect1,rect2,rect3,rect4);


        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to do this? If not, your answer should be provided as a comment instead of a full answer.

Comment: Can you also do the same thing with a given image? So without creating the image in the code? And what about a circle divided in three regions? I am searching for a way in which to automatically detect the lines in a picture and setting these lines as region boundaries.

Comment: If you want just edit image, you don't need javafx for that.

Comment: I have an applicaton made in JavaFX, and this image is loaded (see my question, I made some edits). Depending on some values, I want the application to independently change the colors in the regions.

Comment: Yes, but you could still use Java to do that. JavaFX is just way to show image.

Comment: Ok, so how would you do such a thing? Can the coloring be done real time in a JavaFX GUI without using JavaFX code to color a region? The behavior of the image is supposed to be handled by a controller, and the controller will probably contain a reference to the image.

Comment: @user979349 Could you tell me how to do this? Thank you for your help?

Comment: Here is two options to edit image:
1. get image object from imageView and change it with PixelWriter and PixelReader. Look here for more information http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/image_ops/jfxpub-image_ops.htm
2. Convert javafx image object to BufferedImage using http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html, then edit image and convert it back to javafx image.